# Powershell wkhtmltopdf.exe : libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

Tags: powershell, wkhtmltopdf

Using wkhtmltopdf in Powershell, the PDF file is printing as expected, although it is throwing a warning as follows:

`& "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" --print-media-type -q --header-left [webpage] --header-font-size 7 --footer-left [isodate] $listing.Url $pdfDest`

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe : libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
At R:\powershell_scripts\aso\get_individual_aircraft.ps1:138 char:13
+             & "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" --pr ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (libpng warning:...ct sRGB profile:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I'd like to either deal with this warning or since the pdf is working satisfactorily, I'd like to suppress the warning.   I need some direction please.

Comment: I tried try / catch.  It does not seem to work since it's not a Powershell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from the error that the command is referring to `get_individual_aircraft.ps1` at line 138.

Could you please put

> $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';

in that script and see if it works. I believe that **EXE** is getting called with the help of that script.